# Refactoring help to reduce duplication

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, refactoring

I have several ViewControllers all with several methods like the below (and these are virtually the only methods in the classes.)

```
@IBAction func witnessNameAction(sender: RoundCornerButton) {
    presentTextEntryFromViewController(self, initialText: incidentReport.witnessName, completion: { [unowned self] text in
        self.incidentReport.witnessName = text
    })

    sender.setTapped()
}

@IBAction func witnessDescriptionAction(sender: RoundCornerButton) {
    presentTextEntryFromViewController(self, initialText: incidentReport.witnessDescription, completion: { [unowned self] text in
        self.incidentReport.witnessDescription = text
    })

    sender.setTapped()
}
```

Notice that the only difference between the two methods above is which text variable is being get/set. I'm open to any ideas on how to refactor these methods.

Comment: MVVM architecture could DRY this up. However, it's up to you to determine if refactoring this is a high priority in the scope of the project.

Comment: I'd love to hear more @mattt. The above code is from a ViewModel. (Apple calls them ViewControllers, but they serve the same purpose as far as I know.)

Comment: iOS view controllers are not view models. There are plenty of good blog posts on the subject if you search for MVVM architecture on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from a Java and reading some of Microsoft's excuses for their suggested approaches on MSDN for C#, there are a few ways I can see this being approached.

If the method will only ever have two parameters, create a method that would allow both:

```
function witness(paramA, paramB) {
    if (paramA != null) {
        // Target A
    }
    if (paramB != null) {
        // Target B
    } 
}
```

This makes me think "I have object A and need to create a unified concept in object B"

Otherwise, an enumeration or static integers would work too:

```
function witness(target, param) {
    switch (target) {
        case TARGET_A:
            // Target A
            break;
        case TARGET_B
            // Target B
            break;
    }
}
```

Which makes me think "I have an object that has fields that I would like external access to change"

You could even use if statements which would allow you to specify multiple targets:

```
function witness(targets, param) {
    if (targets.contains(TARGET_A) {
        // Target A
    }
    if (targets.contains(TARGET_B) {
        // Target B
    }
}
```

Which is the same as above in it's own ways.

And last but not least, you could separate the concept and just give self.incidentReport.whatYouNeed as a target:

```
function witness(target, param) {
    target = param;
}
```

But to me, this is more so "I have an undefined concept of an object that must be set through validation or pre-op", which may be code smell in it's own way. I don't see a problem with a setIfValid() or prepareForSet() style function in the Java world, but that's an entirely different can of worms from my experience. The more I look at it, the more I feel like it all depends on a bunch of other factors that you would have to know as the developer - "Will I ever add more parameters?" "What objects know of what other objects?" "Should I be restricting access anyway?"